# Are questions about security design off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As someone who works in IT security, I often browse the security-related tags on Stack Overflow, including [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption), [aes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aes) and [rsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsa).

I frequently find questions that relate to the security properties of a solution, but have no specific programming question. I vote to close these questions as off-topic, occasionally suggesting to post at [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) or [Crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) if the question quality is high.

An example of such a question is: [Secure HMAC shared secret by encrypting authorization hash with RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954405/secure-hmac-shared-secret-by-encrypting-authorization-hash-with-rsa). I voted to close this question, since it  focussed on critiquing a security design.

Here are a few others from my recent close vote history:

1. [Password Hash Reverse with hash salt and the actual password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880028/password-hash-reverse-with-hash-salt-and-the-actual-password) (Now deleted, so for 10ks only).
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646645/format-preserving-encryption-for-small-domain
3. [Reducing size of hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671639/reducing-size-of-hash)
4. [How Encrypted Cookies prevent session Hijacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620909/how-encrypted-cookies-prevent-session-hijacking)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111240/how-strong-is-a-simple-xor-encryption-with-random-iv

A common response from the question author is:

> But this **is** related to programming because I'm writing a program that relates to this question.

Am I right to continue trying to close these questions? Where do we draw the line?

Comment: I think you're doing the right thing. Most Questions about security design don't belong on SO and some might be related to programming (well if the problem is not the code but the theory behind it then it's off-topic) but they are either too broad or give too little info. I think the tags should contain what type of questions are OK to ask here and what other sites there are